# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;) with spring 4.0.5

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm getting this error usually do to the version but in my case I use Spring 4.0.5
Hope someone can help me to find a issue.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;
```

Here is my dispatcher

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<!-- Annotation -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Déclaration des package de base -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.edf.bruteweb"/>

<!-- ajout du view resolver pour afficher les jsp dans le navigateur -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--     Déclaration des beans --> 
    <bean id="bruteDao" class="com.edf.bruteweb.dao.BruteDAOImpl" />  
    <bean id="bruteService" class="com.edf.bruteweb.service.BruteServiceImpl" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/> 

<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

the pom I use :

```
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[all the answer i've found says it's due to an old version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461915/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-beans-mutablepropertyvalues-add)

Comment: are you running inside a container?

Answer (score 0):

This method was added in Spring 3.0, so you probably have some pre 3.0 Spring version jar in your classpath. Check your classpath and your dependencies of maven. There is definitely some version mismatch here!

Comment: Same answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2654125/3003757 ..!! But here user is using latest version 4.0 still he is facing same issue..